# Doing an F test, only sample size, means, and stdev given

Tags: self-study, f-test

I've attempted to Google this problem to no avail. This is a homework question.

There are 2 groups. For each, the sample size, sample mean, sample standard deviation is given. Raw data isn't provided.

How do I use an F test to test for the difference between the 2 means?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Thanks to @AdamO for the tip. I think I got it but I'm not sure. First I computed the sum of squares (SS) between groups by taking (mean1 - pooled_mean)^2 + (mean2 - pooled_mean)^2. Then I got SS within groups by summing (s^2)(n-1) for the 2 groups. After dividing each SS with d.f., I took f = SS(between) / SS(within)

Comment: @Aaron ANOVA is not the only way to produce an F-statistic. First, you should convince yourself *why* an ANOVA cannot be done in this case (at least with the SS approach). Any time you use an F-statistic to produce a test, it's an F-test. You should consult the definition of the F-statistic and a few of the proceeding examples in your text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An F statistic is given by the ratio of two independent chi-square random variables. Under the null hypothesis, the two populations have the same mean: $$\mu_{pooled} = \frac{n_1 \mu_1  + n_2 \mu_2 }{n_1 + n_2}$$.

And so, under the null hypothesis:

$$\left(\frac{  \bar{X_1} - \mu_{pooled} } {\mbox{SE} (\bar{X}_1)}\right) ^2 \sim \chi^2_1$$

And similarly for the second population.